# Listing all installed certificates on android

Tags: android, certificate

I am writing an app which lists all the certificates installed on
the device. But I found that there are two places where certificates
are stored:

1. **System/etc/security/cacerts.bks**: This file contains list of all
   pre-installed certificate. I am able to read this file using
   Keystore class defined in frameworks/
   base/keystore/java/android/security.
2. **data/misc/keystore**: Another way to install certificates (e.g. through
   certinstaller app) installs third party certificate and makes
   its entry in this directory.

But I am not getting how to read certificate info like SerialNumber,
IssuerDN etc. from this file.

Answer (score 14):

I use the below code snippet to list

```
public void PrintInstalledCertificates() {
    try {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidCAStore");
    
        if (ks != null) {
            ks.load(null, null);
            Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
        
            while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {

                String alias = (String) aliases.nextElement();

                java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);
                //To print System Certs only
                if(cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains("system")){
                    System.out.println(cert.getIssuerDN().getName());
                }

                //To print User Certs only 
                if(cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains("user")){
                    System.out.println(cert.getIssuerDN().getName());
                }

                //To print all certs
                System.out.println(cert.getIssuerDN().getName());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (java.security.cert.CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }               
}
```

Comment: cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains("system")
cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains("user") 
for both getting false values every time 
please suggest another identifier to segregate the user and system certificates

Answer (score 4):

For me and my Mac running 10.7.5 and the JavaVM + keytool shipped with it the process described by Shashwat Shriparv is slightly different:

```
adb pull /system/etc/security/cacerts.bks cacerts.bks
wget http://bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk16-141.jar
keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts.bks -storepass "" -storetype BKS -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath ./bcprov-jdk16-141.jar
```

Answer (score 3):

```
1. get the certificates file
adb pull /system/etc/security/cacerts.bks cacerts.bks

2. download http://bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk16-141.jar and place it on $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/

3. run the keytool utility
keytool -storetype BKS -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -storepass -keystore cacerts.bks -list -v
```

Comment: Since Android 4.2 `/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks` is not available.

Answer (score 1):

As I look through /etc/security/cacerts, I see a list of all of these certificates stored as ASCII test.  The parameters you've asked for, SerialNumber and Issuer info are stored as text.  Just open it as a text file and read in the strings you are looking for.

```
# ls -al /etc/security/cacerts/ff783690.0
ls -al /etc/security/cacerts/ff783690.0
-rw-r--r-- root     root         5106 2011-12-13 23:49 ff783690.0
# cat /etc/security/cacerts/ff783690.0
cat /etc/security/cacerts/ff783690.0
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            44:be:0c:8b:50:00:24:b4:11:d3:36:2a:fe:65:0a:fd
        Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=UT, L=Salt Lake City, O=The USERTRUST Network, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, CN=UTN-USERFirst-Hardware
        Validity
            Not Before: Jul  9 18:10:42 1999 GMT
            Not After : Jul  9 18:19:22 2019 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=UT, L=Salt Lake City, O=The USERTRUST Network, OU=http://www.usertrust.com, CN=UTN-USERFirst-Hardware
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus (2048 bit):
                    00:b1:f7:c3:38:3f:b4:a8:7f:cf:39:82:51:67:d0:
                    6d:9f:d2:ff:58:f3:e7:9f:2b:ec:0d:89:54:99:b9:
                    38:99:16:f7:e0:21:79:48:c2:bb:61:74:12:96:1d:
                    3c:6a:72:d5:3c:10:67:3a:39:ed:2b:13:cd:66:eb:
                    95:09:33:a4:6c:97:b1:e8:c6:ec:c1:75:79:9c:46:
                    5e:8d:ab:d0:6a:fd:b9:2a:55:17:10:54:b3:19:f0:
                    9a:f6:f1:b1:5d:b6:a7:6d:fb:e0:71:17:6b:a2:88:
                    fb:00:df:fe:1a:31:77:0c:9a:01:7a:b1:32:e3:2b:
                    01:07:38:6e:c3:a5:5e:23:bc:45:9b:7b:50:c1:c9:
                    30:8f:db:e5:2b:7a:d3:5b:fb:33:40:1e:a0:d5:98:
                    17:bc:8b:87:c3:89:d3:5d:a0:8e:b2:aa:aa:f6:8e:
                    69:88:06:c5:fa:89:21:f3:08:9d:69:2e:09:33:9b:
                    29:0d:46:0f:8c:cc:49:34:b0:69:51:bd:f9:06:cd:
                    68:ad:66:4c:bc:3e:ac:61:bd:0a:88:0e:c8:df:3d:
                    ee:7c:04:4c:9d:0a:5e:6b:91:d6:ee:c7:ed:28:8d:
                    ab:4d:87:89:73:d0:6e:a4:d0:1e:16:8b:14:e1:76:
                    44:03:7f:63:ac:e4:cd:49:9c:c5:92:f4:ab:32:a1:
                    48:5b
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                A1:72:5F:26:1B:28:98:43:95:5D:07:37:D5:85:96:9D:4B:D2:C3:45
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:
                URI:http://crl.usertrust.com/UTN-USERFirst-Hardware.crl

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication, IPSec End System, IPSec Tunnel, I
PSec User
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        47:19:0f:de:74:c6:99:97:af:fc:ad:28:5e:75:8e:eb:2d:67:
        ee:4e:7b:2b:d7:0c:ff:f6:de:cb:55:a2:0a:e1:4c:54:65:93:
        60:6b:9f:12:9c:ad:5e:83:2c:eb:5a:ae:c0:e4:2d:f4:00:63:
        1d:b8:c0:6c:f2:cf:49:bb:4d:93:6f:06:a6:0a:22:b2:49:62:
        08:4e:ff:c8:c8:14:b2:88:16:5d:e7:01:e4:12:95:e5:45:34:
        b3:8b:69:bd:cf:b4:85:8f:75:51:9e:7d:3a:38:3a:14:48:12:
        c6:fb:a7:3b:1a:8d:0d:82:40:07:e8:04:08:90:a1:89:cb:19:
        50:df:ca:1c:01:bc:1d:04:19:7b:10:76:97:3b:ee:90:90:ca:
        c4:0e:1f:16:6e:75:ef:33:f8:d3:6f:5b:1e:96:e3:e0:74:77:
        74:7b:8a:a2:6e:2d:dd:76:d6:39:30:82:f0:ab:9c:52:f2:2a:
        c7:af:49:5e:7e:c7:68:e5:82:81:c8:6a:27:f9:27:88:2a:d5:
        58:50:95:1f:f0:3b:1c:57:bb:7d:14:39:62:2b:9a:c9:94:92:
        2a:a3:22:0c:ff:89:26:7d:5f:23:2b:47:d7:15:1d:a9:6a:9e:
        51:0d:2a:51:9e:81:f9:d4:3b:5e:70:12:7f:10:32:9c:1e:bb:
        9d:f8:66:a8
SHA1 Fingerprint=04:83:ED:33:99:AC:36:08:05:87:22:ED:BC:5E:46:00:E3:BE:F9:D7
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/manishpathak99/X509CertificateInfo) is an open source android app which could help you to see X509 Certificate information-