# List all user certificates installed on the Android device

Tags: android, keystore

To list installed certificates I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/30421940/3143487.

```
cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains("system")
cert.getIssuerDN().getName().contains("user")
```

Both are getting false values every time. Please suggest an identifier to segregate the user and system certificates.

Comment: The issuerDN is a property of the certificate (and thus is immutable). It is totally unrelated to the system or user CA list. So your approach can not work